# Nginx will not stop rewriting

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx

I am attempting to configure an owncloud server that rewrites all incoming requests and ships them back out at the exact same domain and request uri but change the scheme from http to https.

This is failed miserably. I tried:

```
 redirect 301 https://$hostname/$request_uri
```

and

```
 rewrite ^ https://$hostname/$request_uri
```

Anyway, after removing that just to make sure the basic nginx configuration would work it as it had prior to adding the ssl redirects/rewrites it will NOT stop changing the scheme to https.

Is there a cached list somewhere in nginx's configuration that keeps hold of redirect/rewrite protocols? I cleared my browser cache completely and it will not stop.

Comment: Even worse, when I turn off nginx and turn on the default apache config it STILL redirects and Apache has never had this configured

Comment: ps: redirections can sometimes be cached on the browser, so it never checks the server and redirects on it's own, just keep this in mind when you face such a case in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AH HA!

in config/config.php there was a line

```
'forcessl' => true,
```

Stupid line got switched on when it received a request at the 443 port.

Turned off and standard http owncloud works and neither apache/nginx are redirecting to ssl.

Phew.